# ConTeXt: Read an XML file into a buffer for processing

Tags: context, xml

I have a very (very) long XML file, and I am using ConTeXt to turn it into a book.

This works to read the file and output as-is:

```
\starttext

\startbuffer[test]
\input /Users/ramfub/Documents/complete_advent.xml
\stopbuffer

\getbuffer[test]

\stoptext
```

If I copy the contents of the XML file between the `\startbuffer` and `\stopbuffer` commands, it works fine:

```
\startbuffer[test]
<EveningPrayer>
<TitleSection>
<Title>First Sunday of Advent</Title>
<PsalterWeek>Psalter, Week I</PsalterWeek>
<Hour>Evening Prayer I</Hour>
</TitleSection>
<Hymn>
...
<CollectLine></CollectLine>
<CollectLine></CollectLine>
</Collect>
</DaytimePrayer>

\stopbuffer

(xmlsetups)

\xmlprocessbuffer{test}{test}{}
```

However, if I try to read the XML file into the buffer, it does not work (no errors, but no output at all):

```
\startbuffer[test]
\input /Users/ramfub/Documents/complete_advent.xml
\stopbuffer

(xmlsetups)

\xmlprocessbuffer{test}{test}{}
```

I don't want to have to copy 10,000+ pages of XML into my .tex file.

Comment: There is `\xmlprocessfile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to read the file into a buffer first.  There is `\xmlprocessfile` to directly process an XML file.

[image]

For more info read the [XML manual (PDF)](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/xml-mkiv.pdf).

---

If you want to read the file into a buffer for some reason, e.g. to preprocess it in Lua or so, you can easily implement such a macro yourself.

```
\startluacode
function buffers.fromfile(name,file)
    if not buffers.exists(name) then
        buffers.assign(name,io.loaddata(resolvers.findfile(file)))
    end
end

interfaces.implement {
    name      = "readbufferfromfile",
    actions   = buffers.fromfile,
    arguments = { "string", "string" }
}
\stopluacode

\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\readbufferfromfile{\dodoubleempty\doreadbufferfromfile}
\def\doreadbufferfromfile[#1][#2]{\clf_readbufferfromfile{#1}{#2}}

\protect

\starttext

\readbufferfromfile[name][test.xml]

\typebuffer[name]

\stoptext
```